# How can I made a trigger work with two source tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I'm having trouble getting this trigger working correctly. I rarely work with triggers so my understanding of them may be a bit off because the way I have this coded seems like it should work (to me at least) but it does not. If an update is made to tblCollateralAssignment then the trigger works correctly and saves all the information in the tblCollateralAssignmentHistory table (including any information from the CustodianData table).

But, if an update is made that ONLY touches the CustodianData table (for example, only updating the CustodianFrom field) and no field from tblCollateralAssignemnt is touched, then the trigger does not work and the update does not get saved to tblCollateralAssignmentHistory.

Hoping I'm just overlooking something small but I've been staring at it and am at a loss.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[Trigger_tblCollateralAssignmentToHistory]
   ON [dbo].[tblCollateralAssignment] AFTER UPDATE
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS ( SELECT ChainID FROM inserted ) AND EXISTS ( SELECT ChainID FROM deleted )
    BEGIN
    
        --This updates history with the changed records.
        INSERT INTO dbo.tblCollateralAssignmentHistory
        SELECT i.ChainID
              ,d.LoanNo
              ,d.FileDate as BeginFileDate
              ,i.FileDate as EndFileDate
              ,d.ModifiedBy
              ,d.RecordSource
              ,d.AssignmentNo
              ,d.AssignmentFrom
              ,d.AssignmentTo
              ,d.RecordedDate
              ,d.StatusPerTitle
              ,d.RecordedImage
              ,d.AtCustodian
              ,d.AOMComments
              ,d.IsVisible
              ,d.DocXNotarized
              ,d.AOMBook
              ,d.AOMDocumentNo
              ,d.AOMPage
              ,d.CorrectiveAssignment
              ,d.DocumentID
              ,d.DocumentDetails
              ,cd.CustodianUID
              ,cd.CustodianDocCode AS DocCode
              ,d.MASIdentified
              ,cd.CustodianExceptionDescription AS ExceptionDescription
              ,cd.CustodianFrom
              ,cd.CustodianTo
              ,cd.CustodianNotation
              ,cd.CustodianComments
        FROM deleted as d
        JOIN inserted as i on i.ChainID = d.ChainID
        LEFT JOIN ExternalReports.CustodianData AS cd ON cd.ChainId = i.ChainID
    END

--Clear out CorrectiveAssignment if the related ChainID IsVisible is set to false.  This is a trigger enacted cascade delete for soft deleted chains.  Edited records are also copied to history.
DECLARE @FileDate datetime = GETDATE();
UPDATE 
    dbo.tblCollateralAssignment
SET 
    CorrectiveAssignment = NULL,
    FileDate = @FileDate
OUTPUT  
    inserted.ChainID,
    deleted.LoanNo,
    deleted.FileDate AS BeginFileDate,
    @FileDate AS EndFileDate,
    deleted.ModifiedBy,
    deleted.RecordSource,
    deleted.AssignmentNo,
    deleted.AssignmentFrom,
    deleted.AssignmentTo,
    deleted.RecordedDate,
    deleted.StatusPerTitle,
    deleted.RecordedImage,
    deleted.AtCustodian,
    deleted.AOMComments,
    deleted.IsVisible,
    deleted.DocXNotarized,
    deleted.AOMBook,
    deleted.AOMDocumentNo,
    deleted.AOMPage,
    deleted.CorrectiveAssignment,
    deleted.DocumentID,
    deleted.DocumentDetails,
    cd.CustodianUID,
    cd.CustodianDocCode AS DocCode,
    deleted.MASIdentified,
    cd.CustodianExceptionDescription AS ExceptionDescription,
    cd.CustodianFrom,
    cd.CustodianTo,
    cd.CustodianNotation,
    cd.CustodianComments    
INTO 
    dbo.tblCollateralAssignmentHistory
FROM 
    dbo.tblCollateralAssignment AS CorrectiveAssignment
LEFT JOIN
    ExternalReports.CustodianData AS cd ON cd.ChainId = CorrectiveAssignment.ChainID
WHERE EXISTS 
    (select * from dbo.tblCollateralAssignment as DeletedAssignment where DeletedAssignment.IsVisible = 0 and DeletedAssignment.ChainID = CorrectiveAssignment.CorrectiveAssignment)
AND 
    CorrectiveAssignment is not null
AND EXISTS
    (select * from inserted AS i where i.LoanNo = CorrectiveAssignment.LoanNo);
```

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Not sure how you are expecting a trigger on `table A` to also handle updates on `Table B`. You are going to need a trigger on each table.

Comment: I'd guess OP is using MS SQL Server.

Comment: Hi my apologies for not tagging the vendor. I am using sql-server.

@Stu so is it not possible to use a single trigger to populate a target history table from two source tables? It can only be done using two triggers? Basically we used to only have tblCollateralAssignment (which holds the most recent info) and then tblCollateralAssignmentHistory which holds all entries that were ever in tblCollateralAssignment. That data gets there via a trigger. But we've recently moved 5 of the fields out of tblCollateralAssignment and into CustodianData. So I'm trying to get the trigger to work.

Comment: *so is it not possible to use a single trigger to populate a target history table from two source tables?* Yes;  *It can only be done using two triggers?* Yes

Comment: Part 1:

@Stu ok so then here's my next question. The way the trigger is currently set up (the way I've listed in this post) it works correctly in all situations EXCEPT when ONLY something from the CustodianData table gets updated and nothing form tblCollateralAssignment does. But if a field from both gets updated or just a field from tblCollateralAssignment does then it works correctly. I'm pretty sure I now understand why this is happening since it has to do something on tblCollateralAssignment for it to get triggered.

Comment: Part 2:

@Stu

But if we go to two separate triggers this is what I'm envisioning happening. I'd have one trigger that just deals with when tblCollateralAssignment gets updated and a separate one for when CustodianData gets updated. But what happens when a field from both get updated at the same time? Wouldn't the first trigger go off and insert a row into tblCollateralAssignmentHistory from tblCollateralAssignemnt, and then the next trigger would go off and insert a NEW row into tblCollateralAssignmentHistory from CustodianData.

Comment: Part 3:
When what I would really need to happen in that situation is the information from both tables go into a single row in tblCollateralAssignmentHistory.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER checkDuration
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on offering
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  isFound NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT 1 INTO isFound FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM Course c
    WHERE c.courseId = :new.courseId AND c.duration = 5);
  IF EXTRACT(MONTH FROM :new.startDate) = 12 
    THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Courses of five days duration cannot be run in December');
  END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    NULL;
END;
```